# What is the next parameter for in a Loopback remote hook?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I´m new to loopback and I´m trying to learn to use remote hooks now. I´ve read on the documentation I need to provide three parameters. The `context`, and `unused` variable and a `next` parameter.

I usually see that at the end of the remote hook `next()` is called.

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of this parameter in loopback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about asynchronous nature of node.js.

The purpose of `next` is to tell Loopback that you've done all you needed to do in the hook and it can carry on processing.

Since you might need to do something asynchronous in the hook you need Loopback to wait for you to finish it, then you call `next()` and Loopback knows you're done.

*And most importantly if you didn't call `next()` your app would hang which would result in 408 timeout.*

For example if you needed to do request to another server:

```
SomeModel.beforeSave = function(next, modelInstance) {

    // if you call next() here it would be called immediately and the result of request
    // would not be asign to modelInstance.someProperty 

    request('http://api.server.com', function (error, response, body) {

        // do something with result of the request and call next
        modelInstance.someProperty = body;

        // now when you updated modelInstance call next();
        next();

    })

    // same here if you call next() here it would be called immediately and the result of request
    // would not be asign to modelInstance.someProperty 

};
```